# Yii Active Record CExistValidator doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use exist validation rule to ensure that my relation is met (i.e. event_id in table EventOther exists in table Event). I'm trying to use (EventOther.php)

```
    public function rules(){
        return array(
                array('event_id','exists','allowEmpty'=>false,
                        'attributeName'=>'id','className'=>'Event',
                        'message'=>'Specified event does not exist. (event_id incosistent)')
    );
```

and the create new entry in the database (record with id 17 does not exist):

```
    $ev = new EventOther;
    $ev->event_id = 17;
    $ev->location_id = 1;
    $ev->location = "Test Location - hardcoded";
    if(!$ev->save()) print_r($ev->getErrors());
```

which always results in CDbException:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fiss`.`event_other`, CONSTRAINT `event_other_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`)). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `event_other` (`event_id`, `location_id`, `location`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2)
```

Moreover, the validation still passes if `$ev->event_id` is not set, which due to `'allowEmpty'=>false` it should not.

`Event::model()->exists("id=2");` (where record with id 2 exists) returns 1 while `Event::model()->exists("id=17");` returns empty.

Did I misunderstand/misuse CExistValidator? All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array('event_id','exists','allowEmpty'=>false,`

should be:

`array('event_id','exist','allowEmpty'=>false,`

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe how much time I spent on this simple typo! Many thanks, I'll mark the answer as accepted as soon as I can :)