# Yii project unit testing: validators

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

We came to the point where our project has grown too big to be tested manually so we started covering it with unit tests. Now we are facing the dilemma of testing model validation process.

On one hand, validation is a part of the model's logic so it needs to be tested, so we started out with tedious tests like the one below:

```
public function testNameRequired()
{
    $this->object->name = '';
    $this->assertFalse($this->object->validate(array('name')));

    $this->object->name = 'Franky';
    $this->assertTrue($this->object->validate(array('name')));
}
```

But on the other hand, validators (i mean build-in) are a part of the framework and are already tested, so we are basically testing static `rules` array (and it's VCS's task to track accidental code modifications).

We also were thinking about creating some sort of reusable validator test, which would accept `rules` array, parse it and run tests like the one above, but again it's just rewriting framework tests.

So the question is:

Do you test validation in your code?
And if you do then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overlooking the idea of testing: You're not necessarily testing if the validation code works but if your validation **logic** does.

I would suggest you still do all the tests for two reasons:

- Just in case you forgot to validate something, it might turn out that you remember to validate it and discover where your mistake.
- Testing has another purpose: allow for easy [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). It might be that you, or some other programer that ends up with your code will decide to edit it.. If the test is already in place it will be easy to ensure that new version works. Also don't assume that Yii's developers don't make mistakes ;) They're only human too - it comes down to how much you trust others.

If you do decide to test your validation I would not rely on using `rules()`'s output - this should be one of the things you're testing.

Comment: We do trust framework, otherwise we would end up testing everything)  So problem here is that we can achieve the same effect with straightforward rules check. If we refactoring validation, creating custom validator maybe, we will do it order to change logic(not just rewrite existing validators) so we will need to change tests as well. And again, tests give us nothing here but plain text change alert.

Comment: Even with this approach I think it'd still be better to test interdependently just to make sure you haven't forgotten something. Also simple things like typos can lead a lot of time wasted ([as I have previously found out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279404/yii-active-record-cexistvalidator-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything)) trying to figure out what's going on. If you trust that all the validation will always work as expected, code will not change and that you haven't forgotten any validation, then I guess there is no point testing validation.

Comment: What bugs me is that last two assertions : _code will not change and that you haven't forgotten any validation_ can be tested just by creating `rules` array in the test and comparing it with the one in model. (we of course test our custom validators)

Comment: @piSHOCK:I wouldn't be testing validation rules by comparing `rules` array,I would be testing it by pushing valid/invalid data and asserting if the outcome is correct (exactly like you have done in your original question).You might be right and in your case it won't matter at all - all I'm saying is that from experience I found myself in situations I was glad I validated certain fields (and thus their validation rules)/wished I have done. Just a matter of personal opinion and preferences I suppose.It's certainly not the biggest part of your project and can be implemented later if you have time

Comment: Well for the typos there is a VCS. Anyway, I think I got your point, thanks for discussion. (sorry, can't vote you up)

Comment: @piSHOCK: No worries hope this help you at least a bit :)